# List all strings appearing more than once in a file

Tags: unix, grep

I have a very large file (around 70GB), and I want to list all strings that appear more than once in the whole file.

I can list all the matches when I specify which string to search in a file, but I want to list all strings that have more than one occurrence.

For example, assuming my file looks like this:

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--+
| HHID |                             VAL_CD64                             |             VAL_CD32             |  |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--+
|  203 | 8c5bfd9b6755ffcdb85dc52a701120e0876640b69b2df0a314dc9e7c2f8f58a5 | 373aeda34c0b4ab91a02ecf55af58e15 |  |
|  7AB | f6c581becbac4ec1291dc4b9ce566334b1cb2c85e234e489e7fd5e1393bd8751 | 2c4f97a04f02db5a36a85f48dab39b5b |  |
|  7AB | abad845107a699f5f99575f8ed43e0440d87a8fc7229c1a1db67793561f0f1c3 | 2111293e946703652070968b224875c9 |  |
|  348 | 25c7cf022e6651394fa5876814a05b8e593d8c7f29846117b8718c3dd951e496 | 5c80a555fcda02d028fc60afa29c4a40 |  |
|  348 | 67d9c0a4bb98900809bcfab1f50bef72b30886a7b48ff0e9eccf951ef06542f9 | 6c10cd11b805fa57d2ca36df91654576 |  |
|  348 | 05f1e412e7765c4b54a9acfd70741af545564f6fdfe48b073bfd3114640f5e37 | 6040b29107adf1a41c4f5964e0ff6dcb |  |
|  4D3 | 3e8da3d63c51434bcd368d6829c7cee490170afc32b5137be8e93e7d02315636 | 71a91c4768bd314f3c9dc74e9c7937e8 |  |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--+
```

And I want to list only records which have HHID more than once, i.e, 7AB and 348.

Any idea how can I implement this?

Comment: What defines a ‘string’? Lines? Space-separated words?

Comment: Updated the question with an example.

Comment: Look into [sort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and [uniq](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html), plus some [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) or awk. Or just write a program in Perl, Python, or other scripting language you're familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue:

```sh
awk -F'[ |]+' '
$2 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/ { count[$2]++ }

END {
  for (hhid in count) {
    if (count[hhid] >= 2) {
      print hhid
    }
  }
}
' file
```

- `-F'[ |]+'` sets the field separator.
- `$2 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/` filters out the header and horizontal lines.
- `count[$2]++` increases the value at `$2`, the string we’re counting. On the first occurrence this initialises the value to `1`. On the second occurrence it increases it to `2`, and so on.
- `END` is run after all lines have been processed.
- `for (hhid in count)` iterates over the strings in `count`.
- `if (count[hhid] >= 2)` skips any <2 counts.
- `print hhid` prints the string.

Comment: Apologies again. HH_ID doesn't necessarily will only contains digits, and can have more characters then 3 as well.

Comment: I’ve edited the answer. The matching is really only to filter out the header and the horizontal lines. If the file was in a simpler format, e.g. tab-separated, the `awk` script could be simpler.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what each statement in awk command is doing. That would be very helpful for me to increase my knowledge.

Comment: Also, file is pipe-separated. What would be the simpler command for that?

Comment: It’s not _just_ pipe-separated though. There are spaces around the values and initial pipes on each line, and there are the horizontal lines. If it was just `203|8c...a5|37...15` then the field separator could be `|`.

Comment: Yeah. In this case, it won't work. But if the file was  just 203|8c...a5|37...15 then what would be the command be? I have many other files I would need to find duplicate ID's. Some are csv separated, some are psv.

Comment: Something like `awk -F'|' '{ count[$1]++ } END { ... }`.